# hidequery string parameters from the url using url rewriting

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting

In my php web site, I need to display my urn in a specific manner

I need to hide the query string parameters and just want to display the value in the URL 
i.e.

```
mydomain.com/city.php?place='usa'&id=2
```

I need to display

```
my domain.com/city-2/usa
```

Is it possible?

Please help me. I am in a serious situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I am in a serious situation." --- such things never do a good job for you (at least here)

Comment: Dnt have much knowledge of Php, but what you want is REST based API.

Comment: the urn typo is an interesting one, as URN is actually a (rarely-used) brother of the URL

Comment: @shashankaholic: you probably don't understand what REST is, really :-)

Comment: @shashankaholic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer And what OP wants has nothing to do with the whole standard, he just wants to rewrite one tiny url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^city-(\d+)/(.*) city.php?place=$2&id=$1
```

You need to put it into the `.htaccess` placed in the web root of your site. To get it worked you need to have `.htaccess` parsing enabled and `mod_rewrite` apache module (assuming you have apache as a web server) enabled as well.

More in [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: You should add a few more words to you answer, like what exactly is a RewriteRule, where does it go, etc.